# detect unprintable glyph (aka "no font available") programmatically

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, unicode

Sometimes a font or a font at a special fontsize does not support a unicode glyph. Then a placeholder (box with character number) is printed, see screenshot with selected line:
[image]

How can I programmatically detect such unicode glyphs from within Emacs with elisp?
I intend to overlay|replace them with a printable representation.

I could change general fontset, but this is not an option.

*Edit:* `what-cursor-position` states that:

> display: no font available

But I can't decode from the source, how it detects that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

> `char-displayable-p` is an autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>       `mule-util.el'.
>
> ```
> (char-displayable-p CHAR)
> ```
>
> Return non-nil if we should be able to display CHAR.
>     On a multi-font display, the test is only whether there is an
>     appropriate font from the selected frame's fontset to display
>     CHAR's charset in general.  Since fonts may be specified on a
>     per-character basis, this may not be accurate.

---

Add-on by [user Tobias](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2370/tobias):

The [manual says that `char-displayable-p` would return t](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Fontsets.html#index-char_002ddisplayable_002dp-4655) if the character is displayable with selected frame's fontset:

> — Function: char-displayable-p char
>
> This function returns t if Emacs ought to be able to display char. More precisely, if the selected frame's fontset has a font to display the character set that char belongs to.
>
> Fontsets can specify a font on a per-character basis; when the fontset does that, this function's value may not be accurate.

Tests and an analysis of the source code tell another story. Only the case of a graphical display is discussed in the following.
All fonts can display ASCII characters. There is a shortcut branch in `char-displayable-p` returning t for that case.
Otherwise, if the font for the default face has a glyph for representing CHAR that font is returned. That is the first component of the return value of `internal-char-font`. But, pityingly `internal-char-font` is for internal use only.
The real implementation of `char-displayable-p` in Emacs 26.1 interprets "displayable" a bit wider.
It may be that CHAR can be encoded by the current coding system (tested with `encode-char`), but the glyph for CHAR is missing in the font for the default face. In that case `char-displayable-p` returns the coding system and CHAR is represented by a square containing the code point.

For testing whether there is a glyph for CHAR in the font for the default face you could use the following test:

`(or (< CHAR 128) (fontp (char-displayable-p CHAR)))`

Side note:

If `internal-char-font` wasn't internal you could also simply use `(internal-char-font nil CHAR)`.

Maybe `internal-char-font` is really an alternative since the return value of `char-displayable-p` is also not specified in the documentation of that function.

Comment: `(char-displayable-p #xE01EF)` results in `unicode` which means `true`, but this character is displayed with a placeholder only. (as `(insert #xE01EF)` proves.)  Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @jue `unicode` means the unicode box. If it representable by a font then a font object is returned. The right test is `(fontp (char-displayable-p CHAR))`.

Comment: Please consider adding @Tobias's info. This is a good Q&A.

Comment: @Tobias can you add your info to the answer as an edit?

Comment: @Tobias I did some more tests and the results where unexpected. Ascii `a` == `0x61`: `(char-displayable-p #x61)` results in `t` which means `fontp` results in `nil`. So it looks like one have to distinguish between Ascii and Unicode before the test. Could this please be checked and then added to the answer?

Comment: @jue Good catch. There is a shortcut in `char-displayable-p` that assigns t when CHAR is in the ASCII range, i.e., it is smaller than 128.

Comment: @jue I edited the answer. There is another aspect. `char-displayable-p` is also described in the info manual. That description wrongly claims that the return value of that function for displayable characters would be t.

Comment: That sounds like a documentation bug. I'll take a look at the emacs sources.